# Connection to localhost:5488 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Tags: docker, clojure, hl7-fhir, timescaledb

I am trying to run this github repo on docker as specified by the instructions

[Aidbox with Timescale DB](https://github.com/Aidbox/timeseries)

However when running the conatiners one of them throws this error message

> 

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
WARNING: read already refers to: #'clojure.core/read in namespace: aidbox.sdk.crud, being replaced by: #'aidbox.sdk.crud/read
WARNING: update already refers to: #'clojure.core/update in namespace: aidbox.sdk.crud, being replaced by: #'aidbox.sdk.crud/update
Exception in thread "main" com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Connection to localhost:5488 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:597)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:576)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
        at app.db$create_pool.invokeStatic(db.clj:45)
        at app.db$create_pool.invoke(db.clj:42)
        at app.db$datasource.invokeStatic(db.clj:70)
        at app.db$datasource.invoke(db.clj:61)
        at app.core$mk_connection.invokeStatic(core.clj:234)
        at app.core$mk_connection.invoke(core.clj:231)
        at app.core$_main.invokeStatic(core.clj:241)
        at app.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:240)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at app.core.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5488 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:409)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:98)
        at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:83)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:75)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.access$100(Driver.java:57)
        at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.run(Driver.java:368)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried changing the port the database (Which I think it’s what it’s trying to connect to) from port 5432 to 5488 but I get the same error. I have read other stack-overflow posts on this error message but they haven’t worked either.

I have also tried to speak with the company that made this project but as is understandable since this is an open source project of theirs from which they make no money it is not in their priorities to fix this issue.

So hopefully one of the brilliant minds roaming this site can help me out.
If you want more info on what the repo is for
[Bringing data from wearables and medical IoT devices to FHIR solutions](https://www.health-samurai.io/articles/aidbox-for-wearable-and-medical-devices)

Comment: How are you running your docker containers?
Docker-compose?

Comment: "*However when running the conatiners one of them throws this error message*" - Which one? And what `docker-compose` are you trying to start? From what I see, the application should not try to access the database on host `localhost`, but `db`; and not on port `5488`, but `5432`.

Comment: "*I have tried changing the port the database (Which I think it’s what it’s trying to connect to) from port 5432 to 5488 but I get the same error.*" - This cannot work. The database container listens on `5432`. Port `5488` is the host port that the container-port `5432` is mapped to. Did you - by any chance - change the database host from `db` to `locahost` as well?

Comment: by looking at the docker-compose file seems like the database host should be `db`
Please take a look here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: @subparry I will try as you both suggested to run the database container on db instead of localhost asnd get back to you

Comment: Check if by any chance you changed this line
https://github.com/Aidbox/timeseries/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L22
It has to have the value `db`

Comment: Nope, that line hasnt changed. I also tried changing the port it connects to in this line https://github.com/Aidbox/timeseries/blob/fd9410361cb239d1dc782681465ccf0dd3e7de03/app/src/app/core.clj#L235 to port 5432 instead of 5488 and still the same error

Comment: Seems like this is the culprit: https://github.com/Aidbox/timeseries/blob/fd9410361cb239d1dc782681465ccf0dd3e7de03/app/src/app/core.clj#L234
What happens if you change it to `db` ? and keep the port at 5432

Comment: I tried changing that but even then the error says "connection to localhost:5488 refused". Which makes no sense unless it is getting the port and "address" to connect to from a different place which we cant see. Because after searching the files it is the only place that contains port 5488

Answer (score 0):

I see container_name: timescaledb in docker-compose file. Hence host will be timescaledb and default port 5432 if you are trying to connect from another container in same network